# how do I get django runserver to show me DeprecationWarnings and other useful messages?

Tags: python, django

I've recently updated my django installation from 1.2 to 1.3. On my developer system I didn't get any warnings about deprecated calls. But once I moved the code onto my production apache server, I saw many 'DeprecationWarning' messages in my apache logs. 
So how do I have to call runserver to these these messages too?

Currently I call it like this:

```
python manage.py runserver --verbosity 2
```

Comment: What version of python are you running?  See @chrisv's answer.

Comment: I had this exact issue on a MBPro running Python 2.7, but the exact same code showed the warnings on another system with Python 2.6.  @chrisv's answer solved it and is the best way to get the warnings back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runserver command ignores the verbosity option: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15132

I'd recommend setting up a logger and directing the output to stderr: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/logging/

For example:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django')   # Django's catch-all logger
hdlr = logging.StreamHandler()   # Logs to stderr by default
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 28):

[Python 2.7 disables the display of DeprecationWarning by default](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html)

To re-enable it, set environment variable PYTHONWARNINGS to "d":

```
export PYTHONWARNINGS="d"; ./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: for anyone on windows: it's also possible to set the env var like so:
"set PYTHONWARNINGS=d"

Comment: Nice one...this is easy to overlook and it took me a while to track down.  It's also documented in the [warnings docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warning-categories): "Changed in version 2.7: DeprecationWarning is ignored by default."

Comment: Who says I want to export this settings to my current shell session? I use just: `PYTHONWARNINGS=d ./manage.py runserver`

Comment: Apart from my last comment, I prefer this answer, because it's the least invasive one (no damage to my codebase).

Answer (score 4):

To have your development server *and* your tests **fail** for DeprecationWarnings in order to locate and fix them, you can convert them to errors by adding

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter('error', DeprecationWarning)
# these are less urgent but could also be enabled
#   warnings.simplefilter('error', PendingDeprecationWarning)
```

to your top-level urls.py.

I prefer this approach because it fails in tests and lets me locate the deprecated code one by one in an automated fashion.